# leaflet --> polyline with angle

Tags: leaflet, line

Is it possible to draw polylines with one point (x,y) and given specific angles e.g. for 45 degrees, and given length?
In other words: without specifying the end point.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a routine to work out the end point using trigonometry.  If the distances are large then you may want to get fancy and add in the Haversine formula.  If you don't want to write one yourself, have a look at the leaflet [GeometryUtils](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destination).

Comment: [`geographiclib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geographiclib) is also worth mentioning here.